# scrollIntoView using React refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, ref, react-dom

We are trying to scroll to a specific component when the user closes another component.

Our example is very similar to that down below, taken from https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components

```
function CustomComponents(props) {
  const items = [1,2,3,4].map((x, i) => return (
    <div ref={props.inputRef} key={i}>
     x + hello
    </div>
  )

  return (
    <div>
      { items }
    </div>
  );
}

function Parent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomComponents inputRef={props.inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}


class Grandparent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent
        inputRef={el => this.inputElement = el}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

We are rendering a big list of cards and want to be able to scroll to a specific card by calling `this.refs[elem].scrollIntoView()`

But our problem is that calling `this.refs` returns an empty object at all levels, and so we are unable to attach to a specific element and then fire it when the user arrives back to view this component.

Would like some help on how one would go about solving this issue.

Comment: My real example, I am not using functional components at any level.

Comment: when you assign ref using callback function, you no longer access it using this.refs, rather the class variable name, like this.inputElement

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks for that, turns out our brains were dead, we looked at your comment and that really helped us.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you trying to call `this.refs[elem].scrollIntoView()`? You should be working with `ref`s inside `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`, not inside the `render` method.

Comment: Yeah, we were already trying to do that without any luck, managed to fix it though! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my specific issue by providing an if statement written below in my Grandparent component.

```
inputRef={el => { 
  if (el && el.id == this.state.selectedBuildingRef) {
    this.myelement.scrollIntoView();
    window.scrollBy(0, -65);
  } 
}}
```